# Function on an algebraic curve: can a pole occur at a point in the projective closure of its zero set?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Consider $x$ as a function on the affine $xy$-plane. Its zero set is a vertical line (the y-axis).  When this zero set is considered inside the projective plane, a single extra point needs to be added to obtain the projective closure, namely the point $P_\infty = (0:1:0)$.

The projective curve $y - x^2$ also contains the point $P_\infty$.  The function $x$ induces a function on this curve. But this induced function has a pole (of order 1) at $P_\infty$.

I am having trouble reconciling the fact that the induced function has a pole at a point where formerly (when considered as a function on the projective plane) it "almost" has a zero (i.e. at a point in the projective closure of the zero set).  Can anybody help to clarify the situation?

Comment: The affine plane is embedded in the projective plane by $(x,y) \mapsto (x:y:z)$. Your $y-x^2$ makes no sense as a "projective curve"-it is not an equation and is not homogeneous. The projective closure of the affine curve defined by $y-x^2=0$ is the set of zeros of the homogenization of $y-x^2$ i.e. the set of solutions of $yz-x^2=0$ in the projective plane. There is exactly one point on this proctive curve that is not the image of any oint on the curve $y-x^2=0$, namely the point (0:1:0)$

Comment: @popstack - If $\phi:=x/z$ and if $U:=D(z) \subseteq S:=\mathbb{P}^2$ you get a rational function $r:=(\phi, U) \in K(S)$, and you have two distinct copies of the projective line $C$ in $S$:  $C_1:=V(x)$ and $C_2:=V(x^2-yz)$. Then you restrict your rational function $r$ to these two copies of $C$ - why should the two restrictions be related in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at two different curves in the projective plane: first the curve $C_1 : x= 0$ (all points $[0:y:z]$) and then the curve $C_2 : yz = x^2$ (all points $[st:s^2:t^2]$).

The function you're calling $x$ on $\mathbf P^2$ is really $x/z$, which is not defined everywhere: it is only defined on the points $[x:y:z]$ where $z \not= 0$. So it is not defined at $P_\infty$. But if we only allow ourselves to approach $P_\infty$ along the curve $C_1$, then $x/z \to 0$ as points tend to $P_\infty$ on that curve. And if we only allow ourselves to approach $P_\infty$ along the curve $C_2$, then $x/z = st/t^2 = s/t \to \infty$ as points tend to $P_\infty$ on that curve (let $s \to 1$ and $t \to 0$).

Here is an analogous situation in $\mathbf R^2$. The function $y/x$ is not defined at the origin $O$, or more generally on the $y$-axis (where $x = 0$).  But if we focus on the line $L_m : y = mx$, which passes through $O$, then *along this line* the ratio $y/x$ has constant value $m$, so
$y/x \to m$ as $(x,y) \to O$ just on $L_m$. The function $y/x$ has different limiting values at $O$ when we approach that point along different lines, which is not a contradiction of anything.

Or think about $e^{-1/x^2}$ on $\mathbf R - \{0\}$. Although it is not initially defined at $x = 0$, it has a limiting value of $0$ as $x \to 0$ (from either direction).  And extending this to $x=0$ by setting its value there to be $0$ makes this an infinitely differentiable function at $x=0$ that is quite important: it leads to the notion of a bump function on the real line. Now extend the domain of this function to $\mathbf C - \{0\}$ by using the function of a complex variable $e^{-1/z^2}$ when $z \not= 0$. If $z  = x \to 0$ on the real axis, then $e^{-1/z^2} = e^{-1/x^2} \to 0$. But if $z = iy \to 0$ on the imaginary axis, then $e^{-1/z^2} = e^{1/y^2} \to \infty$.  So even though $e^{-1/x^2}$ is a smooth function at $0$ in real analysis, it makes no sense as function at $0$ in complex analysis (and it has an essential singularity there).

Comment: Both this and the answer of @Jyrki Lahtonen are excellent, but this one wins for mentioning the function $uv^-1$. Indeed it turns out that this is precisely the expression of the function $x$ near $P_\infty$ when $u=X/Y$ and $v=Z/Y$.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the origin of this problem is that the function $f(x,y)=x$, that in terms of homogeneous coordinates really is $f(X,Y,Z)=X/Z$ is problematic at $P_\infty=(0:1:0)$. You see, neither $f$ nor its reciprocal is regular at $P_\infty$, and we cannot really discuss whether it has a pole or a zero at $P_\infty$, *when we view $P_\infty$ as a point of $\Bbb{P}^2$.*

On the other hand:

- when we view $f$ as a function on the zero locus of $X=0$, it becomes
  the constant function zero, but
- when we view $f$ as a function on the parabola, in terms of the homogeneous coordinates as the zero locus $C$ of $YZ-X^2$, we have, from solving $YZ=X^2$, that
  $$f=\frac X Z = \frac Y X,$$ when the latter form makes it plain that $f$ has a pole at $P_\infty$, when we view it in the function field of $C$.

---

At a smooth point $P$ of a curve $C$, the local ring $\mathcal{O}_P$ is a DVR, implying that every rational function $f$ in the function field $K(C)$ either
has a non-zero value at $P$, or a zero or a pole (of some order) there. All according to whether $f$ or $1/f$ or both belong to $\mathcal{O}_P$. On a higher dimensional variety we no longer have DVRs, and we run into this type of difficulties, when neither $f$ nor $1/f$ belongs to $\mathcal{O}_P$.

---

If we rewind back to multivariable calculus, it is easy to think of similar rational functions in several variables that have no limit at a given point. They may tend to zero, if you approach the point along some curve, but also tend to infinity, when we approach the point along some other curve.

Answer (score 1):

Move from the affine plane in $\Bbb P^2$ defined by $z\neq0$ to the affine plane in $\Bbb P^2$ defined by $y\neq0$ (which basically amounts to adding $z$ in necessary places to homogenize everything first, then setting $y=1$ to inhomogenize afterwards). Now you can go back to using your intuition about $\Bbb R^2$ to see what's going on, as your $P_\infty$ has just become the origin of the $xz$-plane.